# Show that these identities are true.

Tags: special-functions

$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[x^{-n}J_n(x)]=-x^{-n}J_{n+1}(x)$

$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[x^{n}J_n(x)]=x^{n}J_{n-1}(x)$

$xJ_n'(x)=nJ_n(x)-xJ_{n+1}(x)$

Where $J_n(x)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^j}{j!(n+j)!}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^{n+2j}$

I'm having some trouble with the first one in particular. Can someone show me the steps?

Comment: Could you give some context?

Comment: $J_n$ is the $n$-th Bessel function of the first kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's $1$:$$\begin{align} \frac{\text d}{\text dx}x^{-n}J_n(x)&=\frac{\text d}{\text dx}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^jx^{2j}}{j!(n+j)!2^{n+2j}}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{2j(-1)^jx^{2j-1}}{j!(n+j)!2^{n+2j}}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^jx^{2j-1}}{(j-1)!(n+j)!2^{n+2j-1}}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j+1}x^{2j+1}}{j!(n+j+1)!2^{n+2j+1}}\\
&=-x^{-n}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j!(n+1+j)!}\left(\frac x2\right)^{n+1+2j}\\
&=-x^{-n}J_{n+1}(x)\end{align}$$